# $(document).ready in ascx page after ajax callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, user-controls, actionlink

I'm having a little problem with this setup here I have a list of `.ascx` files and they all do different tasks in terms of calculations to the controller itself. So on my `.aspx` page I click on an `Ajax.ActionLink()` and this will render that specific `.ascx` file based on the item I clicked. Within that `.ascx` are 1-3 events that will fire 2 of them are `onclick` events and 1 is `onload`. The `onclick` event(s) are easier to work with in terms of I can hardcode it directly in the controls event like so `onclick="$("#toggleMe3").slideToggle("slow");"` and the `onload` must run when the `.ascx` is loaded i was testing this in a `$(document).ready(function(){});` call, this works fine in the `.aspx` page but as soon as I try adding it into the `.aspx` page it doesn't load and its ideal that this works but I have no idea why not. In fact nothing in the script tags work if I insert directly into the `.ascx` page they only work if hardcoded into the control's events, well some of them at least; the `onload` and `onprerender` don't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, after partial postback script specified in $(document).ready was not executed. I found solution here [MSDN - PageRequestManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx)

Looks like adding a script like below fixes the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(myReadyFunction);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using $(document).ready in my partials that get loaded via XHR.  Are the views that you're loading via XHR throwing JavaScript exceptions? Or do they contain malformed HTML?

I typically have my $(document).ready method at the bottom of my partial that I load via Ajax, like...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ callMyFunction(); });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, I added the script tags to the bottom still no luck. I'm using MicrosoftAjax.js to control the Ajax calls and not the jquery ajax function.

Comment: This works for me, at least in FF3.5 and IE7 on Windows XP. However I do not understand why, as the jQuery documention doesn't handle this case...

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time understanding your question...but here it goes.

If you are loading date using AJAX calls, the $(document).ready() event will not fire -- because the page was already loaded.  You are just loading more data now.

If you already know the controls what will apear, pre-load the JavaScript, but instead of just binding using the click event handler, use the live handler.

so

```
$("#myControl").click(....);
```

turns into

```
 $("#myControl").live("click", ....);
```

Sorry if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: if the page is not dynamically loaded, yes.  Otherwise you need the live to preload the event handlers from the aspx.

Otherwise you will have to add some more hooks on the client side to know when the content is loaded, and the call the loaded javascript.