# JQuery - $(document).ready() executing BEFORE element load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So, I'm loading some data from a MVC3 action that returns Json, containing some parameters and content as a string. I append the content to some div. In the partial view I have a document.ready JQuery event. For some reason that function executes before the content is appended and all the selectors I declare in the ready function are empty.

Is there a logic reason for this? Is I set a timeout the selectors see the elements. But a timeout can be very imprecise.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Example code fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aKxy7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coding a method that waits until a selected element in the HTML loaded via ajax is ready.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are expecting `$(document).ready()` to fire *after* all *assests* are loaded. That's not how `$(document).ready()` works. It is triggered when the DOM is finished rendering. Nothing more. It sounds like you want to use [`$(window).load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), which *does* wait until all assets are loaded.

Comment: $(window).load() function won't fire in AJAX requests since I´m not performing a full-page postback.

Comment: Hint: $(window).load() is deprecated from version 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` gets called when the HTML! is loaded. This means that if your HTML loads some javascript that makes changes to the HTML DOM, those `$(document).ready()` gets called before that.

You should either make sure your function is called last or use `setTimeout` that calls itself untill the elements you need are all loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In your $(document).ready function you can call jQuery's 
    $.ajax or 
    $.getJSON 
to get the answer from your server. Then you can inject the json response where you want. No   setTimeout needed

Answer (score 0):

[$(document).ready in ascx page after ajax callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853955/document-ready-in-ascx-page-after-ajax-callback)

I had the same issue.

Comment: I can't use that solution since those JS libraries are not available in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

First off,

```
var elementIWannaGet = $('html-content-div');
```

should be

```
var elementIWannaGet = $('#html-content-div');
```

However, what you may be better off doing is separating the script from the content, as the dom is already loaded...

Consider changing the response to this:

```
{ result: true,
  data: { id: '1' },
  elementId: '#html-content-div',
  content: '<div id="html-content-div">Html content! :D</div>'
}
```

And then change your contentLoaded handler as follows:

```
function contentLoaded(response) {
    if (response.result == true)
        handleError(response);

    // Get the container where the response.content will be rendered to.
    var targetContainer = $('#target-container-id');

    // Append the content
    targetContainer.append(response.content);

    // Do something with your container
    alert( $(response.elementId).html().length );
}
```